# Dynamic h:outputScript name attribute in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using `com.sun.faces` version `2.1.18`. I'm displaying a list of questions and for some questions (based on the database ID) I want to insert some dynamic Javascripts.

According to the [`h:outputScript` tag specification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) the `name` attribute is of type: `javax.el.ValueExpression` (must evaluate to `java.lang.String`).

However, this code is working for me:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{js.questionScripts[question.id]}" var="script">
  <h:outputScript name="myScript.js" library="js" target="head"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

But this code isn't:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{js.questionScripts[question.id]}" var="script">
  <h:outputScript name="#{script}" library="js" target="head"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

The `#{question}` comes from a surrounding `<ui:repeat>` iteration over a list of questions.

I added an output to see if `#{script}` was not empty, but it contained the correct resource name.

Any ideas on how to solve this or implement an alternative?

Comment: Have you tried it outside of `ui:repeat` ? Have you tried with c:forEach ?

Comment: Tried both now, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What does generated HTML looks like?

Comment: No HTML was generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<h:outputScript>` has to be created during view build time in order to be recognized by JSF resource management. The `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time and is therefore too late. You have to use `<c:forEach>`. I'm not sure how it failed for you, but it works fine for me, provided that `#{js}` is a request, session or application scoped bean whose `questionScripts` property is already prepared during its (post)construction and that `#{question.id}` is available during view build time.

```
<c:forEach items="#{js.questionScripts[question.id]}" var="script">
    <h:outputScript name="js/#{script}" target="head"/>
</c:forEach>
```

*(note that you've to use `items` attribute instead of `value` attribute and also note that I fixed the seemingly [improper usage of `library` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used))*.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. The `#{question}` comes from a surrounding `<ui:repeat>` iteration over a list of questions, so `<h:outputScript>` will not work for me then. I'll have to come up with a workaround for my problem.

Comment: Surely that wouldn't work. The `<c:forEach>` runs before `<ui:repeat>`, so it would get `null` as `#{question}` (see also that "See also" link for an elaborate explanation). Either replace that outer `<ui:repeat>` by a `<c:forEach>` as well, or add them programmatically via `UIViewRoot#addComponentResource()`.

Comment: I was thinking of using `ResourceHandler#createResource()` in my bean to create URIs for the needed resources, but `UIViewRoot#addComponentResource()` also sounds interesting.

Comment: `createResource()` isn't useful to you, it serves a different purpose and you'd still end up with exactly the same problem.

Comment: I would just output the Javascript there using the URL generated by `createResource()`. Just tried it and it works after stripping `jndi:/server` from the URL... it is kind of ugly. I'll have a look at `UIViewRoot#addComponentResource()`.

Comment: If you go that path, better use `<script src="#{resource[script]}"></script>`. Note that it doesn't support retargeting.

Comment: That what I was using :) Thanks